# the software (Microsoft visual studio) does not debug

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-web-api

Every time when I create\open an project of ASP.net in visual studio it gives a data error message
(attached a screen shoot)
and does not let debug accept in docker which does not work either.

thanks a head

I have tried to uninstall and reinstall but it sadly didn't solved the issue.

screen shots:

[image]

[image]

Comment: As per the error message, have you tried running Visual Studio as an Administrator?

Comment: You need to create a [mcve] -- and don't use images to show text; paste it directly into the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### base on the message

[image]

### you can run as administrator

[image]

### or config vs to run always as administrator

[image]

[image]

[image]

### Note

- if you double click the solution or project file
- this **will not open VS in administrator mode**
- you have 1st to open VS as shown in the images
- and then from inside VS open the project